# DJANGO change_form_object_tools.html template with parameter that is not the id

Tags: django, url

I have a button that points to a url. At this point I have `original.pk`, but I want to pass `object.country` to the url.

```html
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
<li>
    <a href="www.sometext{% object.country  %}.com ">{% trans "Country" %}</a></a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

**my view**

```py
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
    from .models import Projeto


    def Aprovado(request, id):
            obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)
            context = {
                    "object": obj
            }
            return render(request, "dpo/imprimir/aprovado.html", context)

    def Reprovado(request, id):
            obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)
            context = {
                    "object": obj
            }
            return render(request, "dpo/imprimir/reprovado.html", context)

    def Aditamento(request, id):
            obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)
            context = {
                    "object": obj
            }
            return render(request, "dpo/imprimir/aditamento.html", context)
```

Comment: can you please also post your view?

Comment: already update my question

Comment: I can't understand what's the purpose of <a href="www.sometext{% object.country  %}.com ">

Comment: Also I added an answer

Comment: @IakovosBelonias i want to go to a external link and go with id of my country saved on my object  `https:www.sometexte/{% object.country %}.com`

Comment: I updated my answer, what you want is how to concate string inside a django template

Comment: `with id of my country` then you probably want `object.country_id`

Answer (score 0):

In your template

```html
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
<li>
    <a href="www.sometext|add:object.country|add:.com">{% trans "Country" %}</a></a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: it is not working my url stay like this `www.sometext%7Cadd:object.freguesia_id%7Cadd:.com`